# Convert a list into a sequence of string triples

Tags: python, list, tuples

I'd like to convert a list like:

```
["Red", "Green", "Blue"]
```

into a tuple sequence of string triples:

```
[("RED", "Red", ""), ("GREEN", "Green", ""), ("BLUE", "Blue", "")]
```

Until now I always use this method:

```
def list_to_items(lst):
    items = []
    for i in lst:
        items.append((i.upper(), i, ""))
    return items
```

But it feels a bit ugly. Is there a nicer / more pythonic way of doing this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a comprehension:

```
def list_to_items(lst):
    return [(item.upper(), item.title(), '') for item in lst]
```

Answer (score 3):

The code in the return statement is called list comprehension.

```
def list_to_items(items):
    return [(i.upper(), i, "") for i in items]
```

You can find more info http://www.secnetix.de/olli/Python/list_comprehensions.hawk

Answer (score 3):

Similar to list comprehension, but a bit different.

This is the **map** function.

```
lst = ["Red", "Green", "Blue"]
new_lst = map(lambda x: (x.upper(), x, ""), lst)
```

It basically changes every element of a list one-by-one according to the function you enter as the first parameter. Which is in this case:

```
lambda x: (x.upper(), x, "")
```

If you don't have an idea what **lambda** is, it is almost like in the high school math:

```
f(x) = (x.upper(), x, "") # basically defines a function in one line.
```

Comment: Other answers don't use newlist for store

Comment: Yes, it is the OP's choice to redefine **lst**. Or insert this code in a function, like he did in the question.