# Convert a list into a quadruple tuple sequence

Tags: python, list, tuples

Based on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34831224/convert-a-list-into-a-sequence-of-string-triples), I'm interested in converting a list like:

```
["Red", "Green", "Blue"]
```

into a tuple sequence of a string triple and **adding a counter** (integer):

```
[("RED", "Red", "", 0), ("GREEN", "Green", "", 1), ("BLUE", "Blue", "", 2)]
```

Usually I'd write a method like:

```
def list_to_items(lst):
    items = []
    for i,j in enumerate(lst):
        items.append((j.upper(), j, "", i))
    return items
```

Is there a nicer / more pythonic way of doing this?

Comment: Just `list` changed to `tuple` , answer is same

Comment: It is the same because the answers were not trying to solve the problem for you, instead try to explain how this mechanism works. Based on that answers, you should be able to do this. If the only issue is numerating, you can ask it solely.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
[(y.upper(), y, "", x) for x, y in enumerate(["Red", "Green", "Blue"])]
```

Comment: I like this except that I would probably use `y.title()` for the second element just in case the input is user-supplied.