# How to delete the very last character from every string in a list of strings

Tags: python, string, list

I have the strings '80010', '80030', '80050' in a list, as in

```
test = ['80010','80030','80050']
```

How can I delete the very last character (in this case the very last digit of each string which is a 0), so that I can end up with another list containing only the first four digits/characters from each string? So end up with something like

```
newtest = ['8001', '8003', '8005']
```

I am very new to Python but I have tried with if-else statements, appending, using indexing [:-1], etc. but nothing seems to work unless I end up deleting all my other zeros. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 33, accepted):

```
test = ["80010","80030","80050"]
newtest = [x[:-1] for x in test]
```

New test will contain the result `["8001","8003","8005"]`.

`[x[:-1] for x in test]` creates a new list (using *list comprehension*) by looping over each item in `test` and putting a modified version into `newtest`.  The `x[:-1]` means to take everything in the string value x up to but not including the last element.

Comment: very nice explanation to myself XD

Comment: I used your solution but instead of deleting the last character from each element in my list, it deleted the last element and I don't understand why

Answer (score 7):

You are not so far off. Using the slice notation [:-1] is the right approach. Just combine it with a list comprehension:

```
>>> test = ['80010','80030','80050']
>>> [x[:-1] for x in test]
['8001', '8003', '8005']
```

`somestring[:-1]` gives you everything from the character at position 0 (inclusive) to the last character (exclusive).

Answer (score 3):

Just to show a slightly different solution than comprehension, Given that other answers already explained slicing, I just go through at the method.

With the map function.

```
test = ['80010','80030','80050']
print map(lambda x: x[:-1],test)
# ['8001', '8003', '8005']
```

For more information about this solution, please read the brief explanation I did in another similar question.

[Convert a list into a sequence of string triples](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34831224/convert-a-list-into-a-sequence-of-string-triples/34831291#34831291)

Comment: This works in python 2.  If you are using python 3, the map function returns a generator (returns 1 item at a time as requested), so you need to wrap it in a list call if you want a list (`list(map(lambda x: x[:-1],test))`).  Additionally, the print expression becomes a function in python 3, so you must wrap anything to be printed in parentheses as well.

Answer (score 0):

In python @Matthew solution is perfect. But if indeed you are a beginer in coding in general, I must recommend this, less elegant for sure but the only way in many other scenario :

```
#variables declaration
test = ['80010','80030','80050'] 
length = len(test)                 # for reading and writing sakes, len(A): length of A
newtest = [None] * length          # newtest = [none, none, none], go look up empty array creation
strLen = 0                         # temporary storage

#adding in newtest every element of test but spliced
for i in range(0, lenght):         # for loop
    str = test[i]                  # get n th element of test
    strLen = len (str)             # for reading sake, the lenght of string that will be spliced
    newtest[i] = str[0:strLen - 1] # n th element of newtest is the spliced n th element from test

#show the results
print (newtest)                    # ['8001','8003','8005']
```

ps : this scripts, albeit not being the best, works in python ! Good luck to any programmer newcommer.

Answer (score -1):

I had a similar problem and here is the solution.

```
List<String> timeInDays = new ArrayList<>();
timeInDays.add(2d);
timeInDays.add(3d);
timeInDays.add(4d);
```

I need to remove last letter in every string in-order to compare them. Below solution worked for me.

```
List<String> trimmedList = new ArrayList<>;
for(int i=0;i<timeInDays.size();i++)
{
String trimmedString = timeInDays.get(i).substring(0,name.length()-1);
trimmedList=add(trimmedString );
}

System.out.println("List after trimming every string is "+trimmedList);
```